# Inserting template variable into block tag

Tags: python, django, web

Is it possible to create block names dynamically?
I would like to do `{% block {{obj.id}} %}` but get an error saying this cannot be done
I need to load custom content depending on obj into the block

Comment: You can't. Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to load different html pages in a div in the template depending on the object that is passed. I was going to wrap those html pages in block tags and extend the template and change the block name in the template dynamically to load the correct html page

Comment: I get it, but what is the actual use case? What is the _object_ we are talking about? This most certainly sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).